# Photoshop action for bringing an object in the center of the canvas and cropping it to 120X120 px

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images

[image]

He everyone,

I am currently working on a project which requires me to shift the mentioned asset(in the pic) to the center of the canvas and crop the image to 120X120 px. The current image has the size of 300X300 px.There are around 300 image sequences that I need to do the same to. Was planning to run a batch process in Photoshop, with the custom action of shifting the image to the center of the canvas and cropping it to a specific size.Need help in creating that particular action.

Thanks in advance,
Mayank

Comment: Are your images in separate documents or are they all layers within one document? ..and did you run into a specific issue?

Comment: The images are all separate PNGs. The problem is that the assets in all the individual images are not placed at the same co-ordinate. So, in one image, the required asset is 150 px from the left edge of the document and in the other it is 100 px from the left edge. What I require is that all the assets should be in the center of my required image(120x120px), without me aligning them manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open one of those documents <sup>When you open a document, the top most layer is automatically selected, so you don't need to include that in your action</sup>

   - I'm assuming that the image within all of your files is in it's own layer and is the only layer in the document, if we don't count a possible background layer.
2. **Start recording the action...**
3. `Select > All` <sup>So that you can align the layer in the next step</sup>
4. Align vertically and horizontally `Layer > Align layer to selection  > ...`
5. Resize the canvas `Image > Canvas resize...` <sup>Just make sure `Relative` isn't checked</sup>
6. Save your document to what ever folder you wish <sup>Don't touch the filename, just save, and when you run the batch at step 8, each file will be saved to that folder with their own respective filenames</sup>
7. Close the document
8. **Stop recording**
9. `File > Automate > Batch...`  <sup>Just select the action and path to your souce folder and press ok and wait till the batch ends</sup>